# Barplot in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart

Do we need to specify the frequency of a variable in our code to plot the barplot using Python? Can we plot a barplot for a categorical variable column in a data frame, without specifying frequency using Python?
Example code:

```
counts = [968,116,12] #Here I specified frequency of variable in a dataframe
fuelType = ('Petrol', 'Diesel', 'CNG')
index = np.arange(len(fuelType))
plt.bar(index, counts, color=['red', 'blue', 'green'])
plt.title("Bar plot of fuel types")
plt.xlabel('Fuel Types')
plt.ylabel('Frequancy')
plt.xticks(index, fuelType, rotation = 90) 
plt.show()
```

[Link for Dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l76UNksN1YEtFkYnXTxwscX7OyGjAlu2/view?usp=sharing)

In the first line of code, I specified the frequency of the variable in the data frame. My question is can we plot barplot without specifying that frequency, instead of making it find frequency by its own form data frame and plot a barplot?

Comment: Please provide example of data and desired output

Comment: I think you need a [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), not a barplot...

Comment: @Daweo now updated my question, can you help me?

Comment: @Djib2011, my question is can we do barplot without specifying frequency?

Comment: Can you please add the original dataframe?

Comment: @Rafael-WO, I linked data frame to my question, now can you help me?

Comment: @Lavan see the answer below :) wasn't me though.

Comment: @Rafael-WO thank you for your efforts in helping mw

Answer (score 2):

```
df['FuelType'].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Please select this answer as the accepted answer and upvote if possible.

Comment: I will try to compensate the "not-acceptance" of the answer with an upvote ;)